# Updating an existing web app advice for asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application that is used by several different clients.  At the moment the process of updating their end with any changes is like so:

- Publish/Compile App
- Put relevant files into a zip (not web.config as different db paths for each client and don't want to overwrite)
- Generate scripts on SQL Server for all Stored Procedures
- Add to zip
- Upload zip to Web
- WPF App I created that runs from client server downloads zip, extracts files to web app folder and executes scripts for sql server stored procedures

Now this does work but it requires an IT guy at the client end to run the WPF App to update and it can be days before some of them get round to it.  So what I would like to do is provide the ability to update the web app from WITHIN the web app.  I know I can create a DLL to do the FTP, Extract etc, but how can I get this to display progress on the page?

Or if anyone has an alternative to updating the web app without the need for someone to access the server it's on great as this method makes it hard to let clients know when there is an update available.

Comment: Would automatically running some code in your uploaded website dlls that can execute either the WPF App or do the unzipping itself be of use?

Comment: Executing the code, no problem, what I want if possible is to create a web page that will allow the end user to 'Update now' as it were which runs it but also lets the end user know what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can use i.e.

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Your.Type), "MethodNameToCall")]
```

which is specified in the AssemblyInfo.cs file of a project to do some setup code whenever the application is deployed. This automatically runs on deployment and would allow you to do your copying/setup. You could probably run the WPF App from this code via

```
System.Diagnostics.Process
```

UPDATE:

Having re-read this post it seems clear to me that this is about moving from a WPF app to a web based app. Also it appears the poster just wants a method by which to signal back from the code that is updating the file system on the client side so....

Depending on how complex the input required is you may need one or more pages and a navigation system to go forward and back.

However once all input had been taken and the update commenced you have a couple of options - one 'hacky' the other not so.

1 - Hacky) Refresh the page using window.location javascript and setTimeout along with session tracking to update the progress of the threaded coded behind EWWWWW...

2) Create an ajax function using setInterval to poll the server (probably using a callable method decorated with the [WebMethod] attribute. This method can send back arbitrary data back to the ajax call which is then used to update the UI (perhaps using something like jqueryUI progress bar

NOTE: IF you are replacing anything in the bin, touching the web.config or in fact ANY .aspx page. Then you will restart the server automatically... If this is the case then you will have to code a seperate application that will update the other application from the outside + you should signal to any connected users that a shutdown will occur shortly and start blocking new users until the upgrade has completed.

Comment: Can the end user activate this from within a web page though, that's what I want to achieve.

Comment: @user1166905 well what is this WPF app doing that cant be done by a web page? If the application needs input then create web forms and just do the app as webbased. one caveat - if you are doing dodgy (i.e. restricted) stuff such as special file access stuff AND your webserver application is running < Full Trust you will hit APTCA (AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute) security errors

Comment: It is using FTP to download a zip file, extracting it to web app folder and also downloading another file containing sql server scripts which it imports.

Comment: see update @user1166905 basically yes you can use ajax to get signals from the page that is replacing the wpf app. visitor clicks link to upgrade -> web page does the ftp downloads and puts in correct directories all the time updating i.e. an static int progress -> javascript ajax calls WebMethod decorated method that spits back the int progress value and updates the UI asynchronously.

Comment: and you can proobably just move the code in the WPF app that does all the downloading...